# Boton Export Full Catalog - magento

Tags: magento, export, catalog

How do I enable the Export Full Catalog button or similar option on this page that does not appear in my installation.

[image: 1]

Comment: Please ask a question in English only on StackOverlfow.

Comment: Done, the question is in English